# Convert curl url request to JMeter script

Tags: http, curl, get, jmeter, jscript

I have a requirement to record and perform load test on below CURL URL request from JMeter.

I tried and I'm able to record script if i execute the url only with http://localhost/higs/PlatformHIGServlet\

but i want to record the same url which contains post data on url, when i try this in **browser** i'm getting **404 error** but in **Curl** - **200 ok**.

http://localhost/higs/PlatformHIGServlet\?gs_serviceName=xxx\&gs_serviceType=yyy\

Please help me on this,

Thanking You in Advance

Comment: Try http://localhost/higs/PlatformHIGServlet?gs_serviceName=xxx&gs_serviceType=yyy

Comment: tired and still getting 404 error

Comment: you are testing with browser or jmeter? browser sends GET request and not POST

Comment: I'm testing with browser and Yes It sends GET. I misinterpreted GET with POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The fastest and the easiest way is using [JMeter Templates Feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature):

   - From JMeter's main menu choose: `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"
   - Expand `Workbench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click "Start"
2. Run `curl` command using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder as a proxy

   ```
   curl -x http://localhost:8888 http://localhost/higs/PlatformHIGServlet
   ```
3. Captured request will be available under `Test Plan -> Thread Group -> Recording Controller`

References:

- [Curl manual page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-x)
- [Apache JMeter proxy Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Jmeter has a feature to Create a Test Plan From a cURL Command. Referefer https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/curl.html

To create an import from a cURL, open the Tools menu and click Import from cURL
[image]